# Cookies and session in php

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

If I write this code

```
session_start();
set_cookie('firstname','alice',time()+3600);
$_SESSION['firstname']='alice';
print_r($_SESSION['firstname']);
print_r($_COOKIE['firstname']);
```

This program prints only the session variable and not the cookie variable. Why is it so? Thanks for helping!

Comment: cookies only print on reload. Oh and you've a missing semi-colon in line 1.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for duplicating the question.

Comment: You're welcome. Another happy ending ;-)